# Migrate Cloud Messaging API(Legacy) to FCMv1 on Azure Notification hub

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

**Azure Notification hub** needs **Cloud Messaging API(Legacy)** key to connect with FCM, legacy will be deprecated soon.

So how can we migrate **Cloud Messaging API(Legacy)** to **FCMv1**.

Web API key isn't useful for **Azure Notification Hub** as if you try insert this key into the API key entry for a hub

**Question**: What do I have to paste into Azure's push notifications settings where my FCM key was used before?

Answer (score 0):

They recently introduced a new tab "Google (FCM v1)" on Notification Hub configuration page in Azure Portal. You can configure your FCM v1 credentials there:

[image]

You'll need to generate a new set of credentials to FCM using a Service account.
You can find detailed instruction here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/firebase-migration-rest#step-1-add-fcm-v1-credentials-to-hub

Comment: is there a way to set this via the azure cli? I can't seem to find it if it is possible.

Comment: I just tried both approaches: Azure CLI and Azure PowerShell and it seems that it's currently not possible with neither.

Answer (score 0):

Azure notification hubs introduced FCM V1 functionality recently.

Go to Firebase console, Select your project then project settings.
Then go to Service Accounts tab. Here you can find a button `Generate new private key`. This will give you a JSON file that you will need in next step.

In your notification hub instance you can find the new Google FCM v1 option in the side navigation. Fill the required fields with the information from the JSON file downloaded previously.

With this change, When registering you will need to go through the FCM v1 API, so that Firebase will know you are registering for FCM V1. When dispatching the notifications to users, again you need to go to FCM V1 API.

The latest SDK's should have these new methods for FCM V1 functionalities.

I have written an article describing my experience with the migration
https://medium.com/@pramodyahk/migrating-to-fcm-v1-in-azure-notification-hubs-android-push-notifications-c342d76adfb2

Answer (score -1):

Create a firebase project in google firebase.

[image]

Then navigate to `settings > cloud messaging` then you can find **Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) key**.

[image]

Add the server key in Azure notification hub - `Settings > Google (GCM/FCM)` and click on save.

[image]

I have an application which can communicate with ANH that can receive the notification which I sent and from ANH to (GCM/FCM).

[image]

- By following the above steps, you'll have successfully migrated from Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) to FCM for use with Azure Notification Hub. push notifications will continue to work seamlessly and avoids any issues related to the deprecation of the legacy Cloud Messaging API.

Comment: This is incorrect. You described steps to migrate to FCM Legacy and the author asked about FCM v1